# Getting separated strings from array information

Tags: jquery, arrays, checkbox, html-table, row

The following code stores into an array the row information from the checked checkboxes of a html table:

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script>
    function myFunc() {
    var myValues = new Array();

    $.each($("input[name='selection[]']:checked").closest("td").siblings("td"),
           function () {
                myValues.push($(this).text());
           });

       alert("values: " + myValues.join("  "));

     }

  </script>

    <table border="2">
    <tr>
      <th>Select</th>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>NAME</th>
        <th>JOB</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="selection" name="selection[]"></td> 
        <td>11</td>
        <td>John</td>
         <td>Doctor</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="selection" name="selection[]"></td>
        <td>102</td>
        <td>Anne</td>
        <td>Pilot</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="selection" name="selection[]"></td>
        <td>203</td>
        <td>Laura</td>
        <td>Teacher</td>
    </tr>

    </tr>
    </table>
     <input type="button" value="get it" onclick="javascript:myFunc(); return false;">
```

Now I need to have the selected ids in a comma separated string (if all the checkboxes where selected would be: `str1="11,102,203";`)

And the ids plus the rest of the information in the selected rows in another string (if all the checkboxes where selected would be: `str2 = "11, John, Doctor,102, Anne,Pilot, 203, Laura, Teacher";`).

And I don't know how to do it. I'm thinking in adding keys to myValues array but I don't know if it is a good approach (and don't have a clue on how to do it.. too new to jquery :( )

Comment: Use fn.map and join it http://api.jquery.com/map/   The DOC of fn.map contains example of what you are looking for btw

Comment: Give more information on how you want the 2 strings to look like, requirement is not clear. Should Id's string look like selectedIdsStr ="11,203". And how will the other string look like otherInfoStr="11 John Doctor,203 Laura Teacher"?

Comment: You're right. Edited my post. Thanks, Sanjeev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solved: See if this helps you

Though i am not sure how you want the 2 strings to look like, i have created a demo for you
to fetch different values in a selected row.
I suggest you loop over selected checkbox td and fetch different values in row using next() function.

```
$.each($("input[name='selection[]']:checked").closest("td"),function (index,item) {
...
});
```

JS Fiddle Demo
http://jsfiddle.net/kTDPK/

For strings output check the console of browser.

Comment: I have done few minor changes for optimization in demo.FYI, we can achieve this result by numerous other ways in Jquery like using tr children() or td siblings() or :nth-child() selector, but next() is better for your scenario as there are only few columns in  your table.